Comparing the completion of two sigma algebras
Let $(X, \mathcal{B}, m)$ be a probability space and let $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{D}$ be two sub-$\sigma$-algebras contained in $\mathcal{B}$.
Definition: The completion, $\overline{\mathcal{C}}$ of $\mathcal{C}$ is defined to be the set of all $A \subset X$ such that there exist $U, V \in \mathcal{C}$ for which $U \subset C \subset V$ and $m(U) = m(V)$. We similarly have the completion $\overline{\mathcal{D}}$. These are sigma algebras (see Theorem 1.36 in Rudin's real and complex analysis).
Definition: We write $\mathcal{C} \overset{\circ}{\subset} \mathcal{D}$ if, for all $C \in \mathcal{C}$, there exists a $D \in \mathcal{D}$ with the symmetric difference (a set in $\mathcal{B}$) having measure zero: $m(C \triangle D) = 0$.
Question: Is it true that $\mathcal{C} \overset{\circ}{\subset} \mathcal{D}$ if and only if $\overline{\mathcal{C}} \subset \overline{\mathcal{D}}$?
Attempt: We start with the 'if' part. We have $\overline{\mathcal{C}} \subset \overline{\mathcal{D}}$. Let $C \in \mathcal{C}$ and then get $U, V \in \mathcal{D}$ such that $U \subset C \subset V$ with $m(U) = m(V)$. Then $m(C \triangle U) = m(C \smallsetminus U) \leq m(V\smallsetminus U) = 0$. Thus $\mathcal{C} \overset{\circ}{\subset} \mathcal{D}$.
Now the 'only if' part: We have $\mathcal{C} \overset{\circ}{\subset} \mathcal{D}$. Let $C \in \mathcal{C}$. Get $D \in \mathcal{D}$ such that $m(C\triangle D)=0$. I don't know what to do next...Please elp. Is there a counter-example?
